# Still don't understand how RXJS operator combineLatestAll works?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I coded the following sample and still can't understand the output!

```
import { combineLatestAll, of, map } from 'rxjs';

const s1 = of(1, 2, 3).pipe(
  map(v1 =>
    of(100, 101, 102, 103, 104).pipe(
      map(v2 => [v1,v2])
    )
  ),
  combineLatestAll()
);

s1.subscribe(console.log);
```

The output is:

```
[ [ 1, 104 ], [ 2, 104 ], [ 3, 100 ] ]
[ [ 1, 104 ], [ 2, 104 ], [ 3, 101 ] ]
[ [ 1, 104 ], [ 2, 104 ], [ 3, 102 ] ]
[ [ 1, 104 ], [ 2, 104 ], [ 3, 103 ] ]
[ [ 1, 104 ], [ 2, 104 ], [ 3, 104 ] ]
```

I have looked at the output for a long while, but still can't understand the behaviour of this operator.

Comment: What exactly you don't understand? This should be expected output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you understand `combineLatestAll`, let's analyze the behavior of `combineLatest`.

As per the marble diagram shown [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest), if we have 2 streams of data, then `combineLatest` "combines" the latest values from the 2 streams.

Meaning, of the 2 streams it has subscribed to, unless both of them start emitting data, you will not see any output.

However, what would happen, if first stream is already completed by the time the second one starts.

```
var c1 = of(5, 15, 25);
var c2 = of(6, 16, 26);

var s2 = combineLatest([c1,c2]);
s2.subscribe(console.log) // Outputs = [25,6] [25,16] and [25, 26]
```

In such case, `combineLatest` operator will the take the latest/last value from source1 (25 in the above example) and then start emitting output when the second stream starts (combining the latest/last value from source1 and all incoming values from source2)

What if, there were 3 sources.
In this case, `combineLatest` will produce an output only when all 3 streams have started generating output.

```
var c1 = of(5, 15, 25);
var c2 = of(6, 16, 26);
var c3 = of(7, 17, 27);

var s2 = combineLatest([c1,c2, c3]);
s2.subscribe(console.log) // Outputs = [25,26, 7] [25,26, 17] and [25, 26, 27]
```

In the above case, by the time third observable starts emitting the value, the other 2 observables have already completed. Hence the output resembles taking the latest/last value from the first 2 sources and then combining it with the all the values from third observable.

The above example can also be written as -

```
var s3 = of(c1, c2, c3).pipe(combineLatestAll());
s3.subscribe(console.log);
```

In your original question, you're seeing exactly the same behavior. First 2 observables have the latest value and then it gets combined with each value from last observable.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I ended going back to the definition of "combineLatest", as my confusion was centered around how each of the streams were emitting the values. Your examples are simple to determine output, which I also did, but as you can clearly see from my output, the last value from either stream is not always used. Without running my code, it's still unclear for me how the streams are getting combined to generate the output.

Comment: OK I took another look and it was the map that was throwing me off, and trying to go over my code sample again I see how the streams are playing out!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the question, although I am still unclear about two things
1. When using of operator without any delays why is that variable c2 or c3 is not emitting the last values instead it emits from start.
2. In the question asked by devguy, output shows [3,100] how did 100 got emitted although the first two emits were 104